# How to get various sized vimeo videos to display (new video pushes previous video to new size) in ExpressionEngine

Tags: css, video, expressionengine, categories, vimeo

I am a beginner in ExpressionEngine (and other code languages for that matter). Anyways, I am creating a video tutorial site, I have my expression engine site set up so I have categories in one channel. These categories filter content to the corresponding page. However, I want my site to have a featured video, which will be the newest posted video. Once I publish a new video, I want it to take the main stage and push the previous video to a smaller size. I am using Vimeo as a video host so all videos will be on Vimeo.

Here is my code in my main page for sorting new from old content

```
{exp:channel:entries limit="10"}
<div class="main_feature">

{if count==1}
<div class="video_large">
{/if}

{if count !=1}
<div class="video_small">
{/if}

<h2>{video_tutorial_title}</h2>
{video_tutorial_link}
{video_tutorial_summary}


</div>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

I have them filtering to two different styles. My CSS looks like this...

```
.video_large {
    height: 960px;
    width: 640px;
}
.video_small {
    height: 180px;
    width: 320px;
}
```

When entering my new content/videos. I have been using the embed code from each video and removing the height and width from them thinking the div would then resize it. It looks as if it resized all the videos to 180x340 but for the newest video it looks like it created a 640x960 div, the video just doesn't fill the entire div. I am hoping I won't need any plug ins or anything like that. I am hoping its just something basic I am overlooking. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Chris, consider posting future EE questions to the ExpressionEngine Stack Exchange site: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

There is a jQuery solution for this called [FitVids](http://fitvidsjs.com). It's made for sites which use fluid design, but it should work in this case just as well. It resizes any videos within your targeted container (in your case `.main_feature`) to fill their parent container's width.

You then can also remove the `height` declarations from your CSS (so that you can accommodate videos with different aspect ratios).

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your page it's hard to tell, but I think you have to set the width and height of the embed iframe to 100% and then it should work.

Comment: reanimatedfallout.com This is my site. I tried going into the embed code and adjusting the height and width to 100%. it helped increase the size of the video, but its not filling it up to 960x540 as the div is set to. It looks like it is treating the video as it is still 581x211 or whatever the default size is. I tried using the advanced options and entering in 960x540 and then changing the values to 100% but it still looks like the 581x211 size in the 960x540 div. I can hardcode the sizes to 960x540 so I know the video isn't being capped at 581x211. I appreciate the suggestion :)